AWS Opensearch service auth SAML
I have deployed an opensearch domain on the AWS OPS managed service and I want to connect a local dashboard to the provided domain, 
I have activated the SAML authentication. the issue is that when I launch the local dashboard in localhost:5601 it's redirecting me to the SSO login page correctly when I sign in it's redirecting me to an url looking like
https://domain_name/_dashboards/_opendistro/_security/saml/acs
and the response is
400 Bad request: invalid requestId
 Any idea about the possible root cause ?
